# model.layers[i].get_weights() returns empty list

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Hello I have the below code where I am loading pre-saved custom weights from a .cpkt file into a resnet model.

'''

```
def resnet_model():
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
    base_model = keras.applications.ResNet50(input_tensor=input_tensor,weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = True
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_last')(x)
    x = Dense(256)(x)
    l2_norm_final = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)
    final_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs = l2_norm_final)

    return final_model

model = resnet_model()
model.load_weights(weights_file_orig)


#this works i.e., W has the model's weights
W = model.get_weights()

#this does not work i.e., w,b have []
all_weights = [], all_biases = []
for layer in model.layers:
    w,b = layer.get_weights()
    all_weights.append(w)
    all_biases.append(b)
```

'''

How do I get the layer by layer weights and biases from a saved .cpkt file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which layer does not return weights? You should consider that not all layers have weights.

Comment: None of the layers. They all return empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

first correction :

you are not using multi-assignment properly, correction is mentioned below :

```
all_weights = [], all_biases = [] # wrong
all_weights, all_biases = [], [] # correct way to use multi-assignment in python
```

second correction:

not all layers have weights ex: *Input* , *Dropout* etc. so when you try to get both node weights and bias weights of these layers you will have error indicating few values to unpack, below code should get job done.

```
for layer in model.layers:
  try:      
    w,b = layer.get_weights()
    all_weights.append(w)
    all_biases.append(b)
  except:
    pass # not all layers have weights !
```

if you want to get weights of only pre-trained model(res-net), then before running above code define *model* variable as follows:

```
model = keras.applications.ResNet50(input_tensor=input_tensor,weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)
```